# My meanjs server takes 3-6 minutes to start

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, meanjs, nodemon

My mean.js app is based off the yoeman meanjs generator, with some tweaks (e.g. separating the front end and backend so they can be deployed separately).

I'm launching the app using fig (see fig.yml below).
When I set the command to "node server.js", the server takes 6 seconds to starts.

When I startup using "grunt", which runs nodemon and watch, it takes about 6 minutes. I've tried various things but can't really understand why nodemon would cause things to run so much slower

fig.yml:

```
web:
  build: .
  links:
   - db:mongo.local
  ports:
   - "3000:3000"
  volumes:
   - .:/home/abilitie
  command: grunt
  #command: node server.js # much faster but you don't get the restart stuff
  environment: 
   NODE_ENV: development
db:
  image: dockerfile/mongodb
  ports: 
   - "27017:27017"
```

Gruntfile (excerpt)

```
concurrent: {
    default: ['nodemon', 'watch'],
    old_default: ['nodemon', 'watch'],
    debug: ['nodemon:debug', 'watch', 'node-inspector'],
    options: {
        logConcurrentOutput: true,
        limit: 10
    }
},

jshint: {
    all: {
        src: watchFiles.serverJS,
        options: {
            jshintrc: true
        }
    }
},

grunt.registerTask('lint', ['jshint']);
// Default task(s).
grunt.registerTask('default', ['lint', 'concurrent:default']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NFS saved the day.

The VirtualBox shared folder is super slow. Using this vagrant image instead of boot2docker is much faster.

https://vagrantcloud.com/yungsang/boxes/boot2docker

Also, make sure to disable UDP, or NFS may hang. You may do so by putting this in your Vagrantfile:

`config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs", nfs_udp: false`

Comment: Also.. make sure to disable udp or else nfs can hang ...  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs", nfs_udp: false

Answer (score 1):

It's because your first approach simply run Express server by **$ node server.js**. But I don't understand why i it takes 6 seconds to start? Maybe you have a slow hardware...

In order to understand why the second approach takes 6 minutes you need to understand what `grunt` do after launching:

[image]

1. Lint all this JavaScript files

   ```
   serverJS: ['gruntfile.js', 'server.js', 'config/**/*.js']
   clientJS: ['public/js/*.js', 'public/modules/**/*.js']
   ```
2. Starts two parallel processes: `watch` & `nodemon`

   If `watch` is clear (it watching for files from stetting and after editing them restart the server) what do the `nodemon`? More precisely, what is the difference between starting the server by `nodejs` and `nodemon`.

From official [github documentation](https://github.com/remy/nodemon):

> nodemon will watch the files in the directory in which nodemon was started, and if any files change, nodemon will automatically restart your node application.
>
> If you have a `package.json` file for your app, you can omit the main script entirely and nodemon will read the package.json for the main property and use that value as the app.

It's watching for all the files from `node_modules` directory and in my meanjs v0.4.0 its ~41,000 files. In your case buffering all of this files takes about 6 minutes. Try to add to your `gruntfile.js` grunt.initConfig > nodemon > dev > option `ignore`

```
    nodemon: {
        dev: {
            script: 'server.js',
            options: {
                nodeArgs: ['--debug'],
                ext: 'js,html',
                watch: watchFiles.serverViews.concat(watchFiles.serverJS),
                ignore: 'node_modules/*' // or '/node_modules'
            }
        }
    },
```

You need to determine exactly where the problem is. Try to start the server by three different ways and to measure the time

1. `NODE_ENV=development nodejs server.js`
2. `NODE_ENV=development nodemon server.js`
3. `NODE_ENV=development nodemon server.js --ignore node_modules/`

Comment: I've removed everything but the server resources & I only have 1 view. So there are only 6 files total.  My current hypothesis is the slow VBoxFS. I'm currently investigating using NFS.